# How can I prove $x^3\, \frac{d^3 y}{dx^3} = \Delta(\Delta-1)(\Delta-2)y$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

This equation is used to solve `Cauchy Euler Equation`
[image]
As it can be seen author has provided explanation of the fact how `x (dy/dx) = delta y`

And left two cases unsolved.
Here is how `x^2(d^2y/dx^2) = delta(delta-1)y`
[image]
[image]

Now can anyone suggest a solve $x^3 \, \frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$ such that it's equal to $\Delta(\Delta-1)(\Delta-2)y$ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prove following equation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1403491/how-can-i-prove-following-equation)

Comment: Deliberate duplicate.

Comment: Deliberate indeed. Perhaps the OP doesn't understand how the site works, in regards to questions being on hold. To the OP. I suggest you delete this question and concentrate your efforts into editing the one on hold to help us help you. Posting identical new versions of your question is definitely **not** the way to go and may get you banned from the site.

Comment: Because that was put on hold, I have deleted that one. @Did

Comment: Because that was put on hold, I have deleted that one. @wltrup

Comment: What @wltrup explained.

Comment: Like I said above, posting identical copies to get around being on-hold is not the way to go, regardless of which one you delete. Also, you don't need to post repeated comments to every person who's added a comment. One comment is sufficient. I encourage you to read the [help pages](http://math.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how to best use this site.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for a more general result:** Note that $D:=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}=\exp(-t)\,\Delta$.  Thus, $$D^n(y)=\big(\exp(-t)\Delta)^n(y)\,.$$  Show that 
$$\Delta\Big(\exp(-kt)z\Big)=\exp(-kt)\,(\Delta - k)(z)$$
for any differentiable $z=z(t)$ and $k\in\mathbb{C}$.  Then, induct on $n$ to show that $$D^n(y)=\exp(-nt)\,\left(\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}(\Delta -r)\right)\,(y)\,.$$